# Selenium python : How to extract message from alert?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to extract message from alert message in selenium python

```
<div ng-hide="authorizationMessage">
<div class="ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-form="cohortForm">
<div class="alert alert-success ng-binding" role="alert" ng-show="message">
<a class="close" href="" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
  **Cohort definition is created successfully.**
</div>
```

I tried doing

```
var1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]").get_attribute('text')
print var1
```

But it printed `None`.

How should I extract message - "Cohort definition is created successfully." from above HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

`get_attribute('text')` it's not what you actually need to use to get text from target `div` element

You can simply use `text` property or get `textContent` attribute as below:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.alert.alert-success.ng-binding').text)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.alert.alert-success.ng-binding').get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Comment: Because the A tag is also contained in the target DIV, you will get an X at the beginning of that string but there's not really much you can do about that short of removing it, etc.

Comment: ok... `print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.alert.alert-success.ng-binding').get_attribute('textContent').replace('\xd7', ''))` should allow to get rid of `"x"`

Comment: It wasn't a complaint, it was merely an FYI to OP because he's likely to see this seemingly random X show up in the returned text.

Comment: Thank you Andersson and JeffC , I tried this solution. But it resulted in printing 'x' not the message  "Cohort definition is created successfully."

Answer (score 1):

To extract notification message values from selenium, paste the .text after them.

This is an example code for you.

```
var1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]").text
```